# delete several rows from a big dataset using a loop and grepl

Tags: r

I have a dataset called `data1` composed of more than 214 Countries and regions written in column. I want to delete all the rows with countries which do not belong to Africa.

I know that I can apply the following code to delete a particular row:

```
data1clean <- data1[!grepl("Albania",data1$Country.Name),]
data2clean <- data1clean[!grepl("Andorra",data1$Country.Name),] 
data3clean <- data2clean[!grepl("France",data1$Country.Name),]
...
```

The fact is that I do not want to write this command more than 100 times. I was thinking about a loop may be but mine is not working:

```
x <- data1clean
i <- Country.Names$data1
if(i=c("Albania","Andorra","France"){
  print(x <- data1[!grepl(i,data1$Country.Name),] )
}
```

Comment: Study `help("[")`. " `$` does not allow computed indices"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best method is to construct a list of the African countries and the use `%in%`:

```
# vector of african countries
africanCountries <- c("Algeria", "Angola", ..., "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")

# subset using %in%
myData <- data1[data1$country %in% africanCountries, ]
```

If you are worried about upper / lower case you can use the `toupper` or `tolower` functions to get the vectors to agree.

Comment: You perfectly answered my question. However I still wonder if my question could be answered using a loop.

Comment: It is possible, but inefficient. In the best scenario, you would loop through either a vector of African countries and collect the rows to keep, or run through a vector of non-african countries and collect the rows to drop. Then, after the loop, keep/drop these rows.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this much efficiently with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
africanCountries <- c("Algeria", "Angola", ..., "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")
dt1 <- setDT(data1, key = "country")[(africanCountries)]
```